# How to create `ExpressionType.IsTrue/IsFalse`?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, expression, linq-expressions

## TL;DR

How do you create an `Expression` where

```
Expression.NodeType == ExpresionType.IsTrue || ExpresionType.IsFalse
```

### Background Info

I am creating a custom version of EnumerableQuery, where I rewrite all expressions to handle Null checking. So that when unit testing EF Linq2Sql code as Linq2Objects, accessed `null` navigation properties do not throw an exception, but instead handle it gracefully.

I am trying to implement tests for all `ExpressionType` members. How can I create a expression syntax to create `ExpressionType.IsTrue` and `ExpressionType.IsFalse` node.

[Github Project: Moqqer](https://github.com/michal-ciechan/Moqqer)

### Attempt 1. x => x

`Where` clause:

```
queryable.Where(x => x.L1.L2.L3.L4.L5.Boolean);
```

returns

```
ExpressionType.MemberAccess
```

### Attempt 2. x => !(x && y)

The following `Where` clause:

```
queryable.Where(x => !(x.L1.L2.L3.L4.L5.Boolean && x.L1.L2.L3.L4.L5.Boolean));
```

returns

```
ExpressionType.Not
     ExpressionType.AndAlso
         Left = ExpressionType.MemberAccess
         Right = ExpressionType.MemberAccess
```

### Attempt 3. x => true

`Where` clause

```
queryable.Where(x => true);
```

returns

```
ExpressionType.Constant
```

## Comments

I am guessing these `ExpressionType`'s are only used when manually creating expression trees, and want to return an expresison similar to `ExpressionType.Constant(true)` but with less overhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `ExpressionType.IsTrue` and `ExpressionType.IsFalse` represent the unary operators [`true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx) and [`false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx) respectively.  They're not "lower overhead" stand-ins for the constant bools.

That said, I haven't been able to get an expression to "automatically" create one of these nodes.  The compiler will simply emit a call to `op_true` which shows up as a `ExpressionType.Call`.  So it looks like it really shows up when manually building expression trees.  In fact, you can create this type by calling [`Expression.IsTrue( Expression e )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd549116(v=vs.110).aspx).